# Too many custom markers on Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Data Structure (ada) that stores lat/long, title and drawable for each marker. There are many markers (~500) and i would like to show the markers only on the currently viewable area. (The relevant code is posted below.)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ada.size(); i++) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (Float.parseFloat(ada.get(i).latitude) * 1E6),
                    (int) (Float.parseFloat(ada.get(i).longitude) * 1E6));

            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(ic.get(ada.get(i).brand_front_thumbnail));
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(
                    point, ada.get(i).title);
            overlayitem.setMarker(d);
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        }
```

I can check if the geopoint is within screen coordinates and set drawable only if it is inside, but how do i update the map when the map is moved?